# Hermitian operator: Eigenfunction conjugate for the same eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

In section 17.3.4 of the textbook Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering, the author claims that since
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}y_i = \lambda_i \rho y_i
\end{align*}
for an Hermitian linear operator $\mathcal{L}$ and any eigenvalue-eigenfunction pair $\lambda_i,  y_i$, if we apply complex conjugate on both sides, then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}y_i^* = \lambda_i^* \rho y_i^* = \lambda_i \rho y_i^*
\end{align*}
as the eigenvalue has to be real for Hermitian operator. Then $y_i$ and $y_i^*$ both correspond to the same eigenvalue. But the problem is that when applying complex conjugate on both sides, isn't $\mathcal{L}$ turned to $\mathcal{L}^*$ as well? So the argument would not hold. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If $T$ is a Hermitian operator, then it is self-adjoint and $T = T^*$...

Comment: @UltimateApple wait but isn’t the definition of adjoint =/= conjugate? The book defines adjoint using integral with two functions...

Comment: @UltimateApple for example, -i d/dx can be Hermitian, but isn’t its complex conjugate does not equal to itself?